# Admin check on certain statements - cannot pass true/false value

Tags: php

Firstly, please forgive me if i don't give enough info in my question, i'm new to the developer scene after just landing myself an amazing opportunity as a junior software developer role a few weeks ago.

I have a project i'm working on which is a basic CRUD management system.
I have a login process and user accounts all setup but i would like certain things to require "Admin" privileges like deleting items from my inventory.

So currently everything works as is (just no admin checking)

i have made this function in my config.php (which is included on every page through the header)

```
function checkAdmin($conn)
{
    $id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT admin FROM members WHERE id = $id";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $admin = $rs['admin'];
    if($admin == 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do i then pass that value "true/false" into my query.
Im using jQuery/Ajax to do my queries but i understand this would be handed on my "ajax.php" page where all my queries are.
my current code is:

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteID']))
{
    if('checkAdmin' == true){
    $id = $_GET['deleteID'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id=$id";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    recordLog($conn, "Members", "Removed user #$id");

    $data = [
            'success'   =>  true
    ];
    }else{
        $data = [
                'error' =>  'Admin Privileges Required'
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

the actual code in itself works, without the `If(checkAdmin ==` statement but i dont think i'm on the right lines with it.

Thanks in advance for any help :) please let me know if any more info is needed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you should try to extract a [mcve] from your code for posting here. That avoids the case of both too much code and too little.

Comment: Why not hide the delete button unless checkAdmin == true?

Comment: nice suggestion @Ralph but as i'm learning to code at the moment it's probably better that i use this method as i have to link my code in other places giving me more of an understanding. I will definitely add that in at some point though :)

Comment: p.s. @Ralph - hiding the buttons from non admins works a treat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function in the `if` statement:

```
if(checkAdmin($conn) == true){
```

Alternately you could do:

```
$checkAdmin = checkAdmin($conn);
if($checkAdmin == true){
```

Be advised that you are at serious risk of SQL Injection.  Implement this now: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?r=SearchResults&s=1|1034.2759) This is bad, bad, bad:

```
$id = $_GET['deleteID'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE id=$id";
```

Comment: thanks for the help :) yeah this is never going to be hosted, i am learning the basics of PHP at the moment and my next set of things to look at is ways to avoid my code being broken :) thank you for the link, this will help :)

Comment: Learn to do it correctly so you are practiced at it in the future.

Comment: just want to thank you again for pointing out the vulnerabilities. I am now in practice... Upvotes for you :)